# Reading file names from an azure file_storage directory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a file_storage within my azure portal which is roughly like :

```
- 01_file.txt
- 02_file.txt
- 03_file.txt
```

In azure data studio I have a data set which is linked to this file storage.

If possible, I would like to loop through this directory and get a list of all the file names in my ETL Pipeline.

I've had a look at the `For Each` and `look up` but I can't figure out how to apply it to the directory.

the end result would be a list of file_names that I would then carry out some further procedures before ingesting the data into azure.

my current work around is to create a JSON file which lists the file_names when I load the data into the file-storage and parse that using `look up` and `For Each` but I'd like to know if there is a better solution using datafactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use [GetMetadata-Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity). You could get folder metadata then get file name lists by accessing childItem properties. More details,please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#get-a-folders-metadata

Pipeline configuration:

[image]

Execution:

[image]

Comment: many thanks for this - will have a check as soon as I'm in the office. The `binary1` listed as your dataset I assume is just a link to the file-storage folder?

Comment: @Datanovice That's just a blob storage dataset which i created,

Comment: ah, my problem here is that I'm working with a file store (client requirements) and not a blob storage. I'll guess I'll have to create a JSON on each upload. Thanks for your help (day 2 on databricks)! I'll green tick as your answer is essentially correct and will help anyone else who searches for this in future.